# Changing iSeries Device and PC console password

Tags: console, ibm-midrange

I am setting up first console session on iSeries.

How do reset console password on PC and iSeries without access to a console?

Comment: This is not a programming related question and belongs on serverfault.com instead.

Comment: I flagged it for moving.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the control panel to reset the password without an available console: [Resetting the QCONSOLE device profile password from the control panel](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/rzamh/rzamhresetqconsoledevpwd.htm)